# no function clause matching in Phoenix.Socket.Message.from_map!/1 when connecting a socket

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

```
** (exit) exited in: Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket.resume()
** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Phoenix.Socket.Message.from_map!/1
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/socket/message.ex:22: Phoenix.Socket.Message.from_map!(["16", "16", "public:subtopic", "phx_join", %{}])
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/transports/websocket.ex:106: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket.ws_handle/3
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy_websocket.ex:77: Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket.websocket_handle/3
    (cowboy) /home/anil/ex_pusher_lite-master/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_websocket.erl:588: :cowboy_websocket.handler_call/7
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy_websocket.ex:49: Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket.resume/3
    (cowboy) /home/anil/ex_pusher_lite-master/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Please provide informations how exactly you are connecting to the websocket.

Comment: @PatNowak let socket = new Socket("ws://localhost:4000/socket", {
  
    })
    socket.connect(). i am trying to connect from my rails app.

Comment: @AnilKumar Add that detail to your question.  Posting that detail in a comment is not the right way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

`Phoenix.Socket.Message.from_map!()` takes a map and converts it into a message struct.  Somehow, you're passing a list into it, which is why you're getting an error stating that there isn't a version of `Phoenix.Socket.Message.from_map!()` that accepts a list.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Also, please put some effort into formatting what you are posting.

Comment: I disagree. This IS the answer to why he's getting the error.  He's passing a list into a function that expects a map.  If you have a better answer, please provide it.

Comment: Fair enough. I retracted my downvote. The wording “somehow” usually means that is not an exact answer and it has no value for the future readers, and SO is the knowledge base created in favor of future readers, not to help particular persons posting poor quality questions, though.

Comment: You have a good point.  I spend all day looking at Elixir stack traces, so it was easy to see the issue, but you're right, it isn't a very good question because it doesn't include anything but the stack trace, and isn't very helpful to future readers.  Thanks for changing the formatting too.